# Panel data or time series regression? | using R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data

I have data for n variables (external funding, staff,...) for m objects (e.g. Universities) for 5 years each.

I want to estimate some models being external funding the dependent variable. For each year there are about 400 observations for each variable, e.g. in 2010 there are 400 universities. For each universities there are data of external funding, number of staff, share of staff in different scientific fields,....

I have some hypotheses I want to test. Most are simple, e.g. "Higher share of engineer = higher external funding". My intended goal is to make projections of future change in external funding for universities depending on an changing number of staff, increased federal funding and so on.

Right now I am wondering what the best approach is. A time series regression (using dnylm) is my favorite (as I can use lagged variables, ect) but I am not sure how to prepare the data or set up the code in R to make it work.

As I am not sure on how to do this I was thinking about setting it up as an panel data model, but I would lose all the features a time series regression comes with.

Does anybody have a tip or some hints for me?

Comment: A couple questions. When you say you have 400 observations for each variable are you saying that you have, per university 400 observations per variable or per university, per year? If it is 400 observations per university, per year are those 400 observations time-stamped in any way (i.e., is it 400 repeated observations within the same year)? Finally, do you have specific hypotheses about changes over time related to your measures of interest?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. I edited my post to answer your questions. I hope I have been able to make myself clear.

Comment: So it sounds as though your unit of analysis is the university and you have repeated measures about each university for approximately 5 years. One measure (external funding) is your primary variable of interest, and you would like to predict external funding as a function of different features of each university. More or less sound like I am on track?

Comment: @MattBarstead I read it the same way you did. BTW, this is sad - universities having to optimize hiring not for better research, but for higher funding. I know it's just how things are, but...maybe hiring more  engineers would lead to better funding, not better science. Absolutely no offense implied to engineers - I was just referring to the example made by the OP.

Comment: Note that this is an observational study. However, it seems to me that you are really interested in causal inference. If I'm correct, you don't have the correct type of data for your goal. Be very careful. I'm not an expert on causal inference so I can't help. [This tutorial](https://cs.nyu.edu/~shalit/slides.pdf) seemed nice (and fun) to me, however since again I'm not acquainted with the field, I cannot testify for its validity.

Comment: Have you thought about mixed effects models (could use `lme4` in R)? You can lag variables to include previous year data and you would be able to account for the nested structure of the data. You would also have the option to examine predictors of changes in funding over time. Structural equation models may be another route to consider as well depending on the complexity of your final model (i.e., if you want to examine multiple parallel change processes simultaneously).

Comment: @MattBarstead Thanks again! Yes, you are on track. I will have a look at mixed effects models! I was wondering, if the plm package will do the trick, but it seems that the lme4 package is better suited for what I want do.